# Django 1.8 cannot locate static css file

Tags: python, html, css, django

On my development env, I get this error when trying to access static css file:

> Page not found (404)
>
> Request Method:   GET Request URL:
>
> http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/styles.css

Some lines from the `settings.py`:

```
DEBUG = True

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
)

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Path to my `styles.css` file (where `eshop` is a root folder of my project):

> /eshop/static/styles.css

Relevant lines from my *html* file:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'styles.css' %}" />
    ...
```

Could you please advice on what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following to your `settings.py` file:

```
# define global static
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

Or just put the static files inside each app:

```
app_folder/static/app_name
```

Comment: That totally worked! Thank you very much! A shame that the official docs say nothing about it.